# What happens to the energy bands when a forward bias > Buit-in potential is applied

Tags: diodes, energy, bias, pn-junction

When we applied a forward bias across a PN junction, the barrier height of the depletion region reduces.

What will happen to the energy bands when we apply the forward bias greater that the built-in potential?